# How to read spaces and line breaks from a textField django

Tags: python, html, django, textfield

I have created a textField model that is sended from a ..

But my problem is simple... How can i specify a line break in the textField? 
to avoid that the text will show all fluid without spaces or line breaks.

It shows me the text like this:

[image]

As you can see, without line breaks...

Hope you can help me, thank you!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

**linebreaks**

Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br>`) and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).

For example:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

If value is `Joel\nis a slug`, the output will be `<p>Joel<br>is a slug</p>`.